# Why is my portainer and traefik not public available?

Tags: docker-compose, stack, traefik, portainer

I'm setting up a docker swarm and try to get working traefik reverse and portainer+agent on docker manager. But the container isnt public available.

I'm new to docker and reverse proxys so i dont tried more than the code showing up.

Starting with:
docker stack deploy -c stack.yml stack0

stack.yml

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: --docker.swarmmode
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefikdata:/etc/traefik
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role==manager]

  portainer-agent:
    image: portainer/agent
    environment:
      AGENT_CLISTER_ADDR: tasks.agent
      AGENT_PORT: 9001
      LOG_LEVEL: debug
    ports:
      - target: 9001
        published: 9001
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes
    networks:
      - portainer-agent_network
      - traefik-net
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints: [node.platform.os == linux]

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    command: -H tcp://tasks.agent:9001 --tlsskipverify
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "./portainerdata:/data"
    networks:
      - portainer-agent_network
      - traefik-net
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.port=9000"
        - "traefik.docker.network=stack0_traefik-net"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:portainer.intern.domain.tld"

networks:
  traefik-net:

  portainer-agent_network:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

traefikdata/traefik.toml

```
logLevel = "INFO"
  defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[web]
  address = ":8080"

[docker]
  domain = "traefik.intern.domain.tld"
  watch = true
  exposedbydefault = false

 # Force HTTPS
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

 # Let's encrypt configuration
 [acme]
   email="network@techgods.biz"
   storage="/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
   entryPoint="https"
   acmeLogging=true
   OnHostRule=true
   [acme.httpChallenge]
     entryPoint = "http"
```

I expect a running Traefik reverse Proxy, UI reachable over traefik.intern.domain.tld and portainer reachable over portainer.intern.domain.tld

Answer (score 1):

For complete explicitness, I would also put the `entryPoints` definition:

```
- "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https"
```

Are you positive that this part is correct?

```
- "traefik.docker.network=stack0_traefik-net"
```

It doesn't seem to align with your network definitions:

```
networks:
  traefik-net:

  portainer-agent_network:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

I'd highly recommend getting this working without the network definitions and then later adding these one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying to revive my stack.yml i started from beginning, read a bit more of documentation and found much helpful stackoverflow posts.

At the end, I'm actually having this:

```
version: "3"

services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    command: --web --docker --docker.swarmmode --docker.watch --docker.domain=intern.domain.tld --logLevel=DEBUG
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role==manager]
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    labels:
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.intern.domain.tld"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "5003:8080"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /dev/null:/traefik.toml
    networks:
      - proxy

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer:latest
    command: --no-auth -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      labels:
        - "traefik.portainer.port=9000"
        - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:portainer.intern.domain.tld"
    ports:
      - "5001:9000"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
```

Now i would need to get the portainer agent working. I'll work on it. On the first view portainer and traefik reachable on the right ports. SSL not yet, but for this my questions below.

- Actually `portainer.intern.domain.tld:5001` and `traefik.intern.domain.tld:5001` both still `portainer`, but `traefik.intern.domain.tld:5001` should not be reachable - just `:5003` with `traefik` - Also the other way round.
- In the documentation, I've read that for cluster operation, kv storage is needed to use acme certificates across multiple hosts. Nevertheless, I found configurations with the acme.json configuration in the network (for the swarm operation). Is kv storages obligatory or not?
- I would really appreciate if their is a basic auth for the first in front of portainer and traefik - later wanna edit this to certificates. I know a bit about configuration in the traefik.toml - but is it the right way, if i done anything else over the compose file?
- Same for SSL - i know a bit about configuration over traefik.toml, but is it the right way? What about storing all this in the compose file?

thank u in advance.

Comment: put traefik.enable=true label as your config specify not exposed by default